# Use the iphone gyroscope with some animation and dirac LE

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, nstimer, gyroscope

I'm trying to make an application with the same "goal" that Power Ball (for those who know what it is ;)

When the player move his iphone from left to right, i use the gyroscope values to make some picture turn and change the speed/pitch of a music sample.

Here is my issue : 
 For the gyroscope it's OK
 For the music it's OK
 But for the animation i dont really know.

I tried this method with NSTimer :

```
//Start the timer
[timerRotationImage invalidate];
timerRotationImage = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(TimerRotateImage:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];

//Make a picture turn with some angle
uiImageRotate.center = CGPointMake(160, 140);
angleRotation = angleRotation + 0.3;
uiImageRotate.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleRotation);

//For the acceleration/deceleration
[timerRotationImage setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:timerRotationImage.timeInterval / (uiDurationSlider.value*50)]];
```

The thing is that sometimes at high speed the picture seems to be decelerating

Could you give me other methods/More efficients ?

---

For now i have tried some possibilities :

- This method with NSTimer and CGAffineTransformMakeRotation
- Another one with CALayer and CABasicAnimation
- And a last one with UIImageView and animation (with an array of image .jpg)

What i am still not able to do is update the speed of the rotation/change it in real time. None of these methods are working =( need some help here !

Comment: Why do you use a timer? Why don't you just update the transform whenever you get new gyro data? Animating the rotation when updates come as often as gyro gives them will most likely just make it seem like it is lagging.

Comment: I came up with a different aproach. I used cocos2d for the animations... I have a game loop : 
[self schedule:@selector(gameLoop:) interval: 1/60.f]
and the NSOperationQueue of the gyroscope at the same time. Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for your answer